# .NET 6 Blazor Server/Client app in Azure. DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement only when deployed, works fine locally

Tags: azure, authentication, blazor, azure-managed-identity

I have a new .NET 6 Blazor app using the built in ApplicationUser and ApplicationDb authentication using

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

When running locally it works fine, however when I deploy it to Azure, I get the following immediately when the "Log In" link is clicked at the top of the page.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
```

I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and am just stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging using user ID under Azure Active Directory (AAD) so you have need to modify Settings:

Authentication / Authorization
App Service Authentication, "ON" =>> choose: Log in With Azure Active Directory
Select 'ActivityProvider', AAD.
Configured (Express: Existing APP)
Manage Azure Active Directory: Manage Permission & Manage Application For Manage Permission ==>> Add, In Delegate Permission, choose: Sign in and read user profile and refresh your browser to login again.

And even check more in KUDO Console.